Are Artin-Tits groups ordered groups?
We consider Artin-Tits groups of two generators $(I_2(n))$. Are these groups ordered groups?

Do you mean "right-orderable" or "bi-orderable"? (Also it is useful to distinguish between "orderable" = there exists an order, and "ordered" = some order is fixed.)

The question in the body is much weaker than the question in the title. These "dihedral' Artin groups arise as link complements, so are certainly left-orderable.

Actually, I want to know about dihedral Artin Groups. Somewhere I have studied they are left orderable and somewhere I studied these are right orderable. If I take a subset of the Artin group say {a,b, ba, a^2b, a^3b, b^2a} can I compare these elements ? If a<b can I compare the rest of the elements of the set?

Your question is answered in Mulholland and Rolfsen's article Local indicability and commutator subgroups of Artin groups. On the one hand, the Artin-Tits group $A(I_2(n))$ is not bi-orderable because it does satisfy the unique root extraction property. This is an easy consequence of the usual presentation defining $A(I_2(n))$. (See Theorem 5.8.) On the other hand, $A(I_2(n))$ is orderable. This can be justified either by saying that $A(I_2(n))$ is locally indicable (indeed, its commutator subgroup is free) or by saying that $A(I_2(n))$ can be embedded into a braid group. (See Theorem 5.9)

Thanks for the reply! I'll take a look.
